# How does CosmosDB distribute throughput when provisioned per database (shared RUs)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem understading how distribution of provisioned throughput works if I set up Cosmos DB to use shared RUs - setting RUs at database level.

I know when set on container (collection) level that throughput is divided between logical partitions e.g. if collection has provisioned throughput 400 RU/s and 10 logical partitions then throughput for each partition is 400/10 = 40 RU/s.

But what about when throughput is set per database? 
Only documentation I found is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database
As far as I can tell difference is that physical partitions are not dedicated to single container but can host logical partitions from different containers  - does this mean that throughput is divided between all logical partitions of all collections/containers?

For example: I have database with throughput 1000 RU/s and 2 collections, one with 3 logical partitions and second with 7 logical partitions, so is throughput divided 1000 / (3 + 7) = 100 RU/s for each logical partition?

OR
Is throughput reserved for all collections/partitions in sum? e.g. there is database with 1000 RU/s and one logical partitions use 800RU/s and other use 200RU/s (no matter what collection) then is it ok as long as they in sum dont exceed 1000 RU/s ?

Maybe question is short - is shared throughput distributed evenly between logical partitions (same as when set on collection level) or is not (somehow different)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. If you are configuring the throughput at database level. You cannot guarantee the throughput for each containers in it, unless you configure the throughput for containers as well.

All containers created inside a database with provisioned throughput must be created with a partition key. At any given point of time, the throughput allocated to a container within a database is distributed across all the logical partitions of that container. When you have containers that share provisioned throughput configured on a database, you can't selectively apply the throughput to a specific container or a logical partition.

You can follow this URL for understading the effect of setting throughput at database and containers level.
[Set throughput on a database and a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database-and-a-container)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe question is short - is shared throughput distributed evenly between logical partitions (same as when set on collection level) or is not (somehow different)?

The answer is 'it is not'

This answer you're looking for is in the same page you have been looking at (I have also confirmed with with MS Support).

In this section
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#comparison-of-models

> RUs assigned or available to a specific container (with database level provisioned throughput, manual or autoscaled):
>
> No guarantees. RUs assigned to a given container depend on the properties. Properties can be the choice of partition keys of
> containers that share the throughput, the distribution of the
> workload, and the number of containers.

Basically Cosmos has an algorithm that works out how to allocate the provisioned database level throughput across the containers in the database.

I would expect there is some performance costs to the algorithm similar to standard autoscaling where if there was a burst of RU demand, the autoscaling won't scale up unless it is sustained for a certain period.

There is an exception if you do the database and container throughput provisioning where 1 or more containers has a fixed provisioned throughput. They would just be separate to the other containers that would share the database throughput. These containers would behave as you mentioned on how a standard container level throughput do e.g. divided among the partitions